# Если примитивы это тоже объекты, почему 'a' === 'a' //true

Tags: javascript

Примитивы в js сравниваются по значению:

```
'vasya' === 'vasya' //true
```

Объекты сравниваются по ссылке:

```
const a = {a: 1}
const b = (a: 1}

a === b //false
```

Если примитивы это тоже объекты, то прочему они сравниваются не по ссылке ?
Подозреваю, что примитивы все же не по-настоящему объекты.

Comment: "примитивы это тоже объекты" - что?

Comment: Примитивы - это вообще не объекты :) . На то они и примитивы. А объект создаётся в момент когда примитиву например точку ставишь и от него хочешь какое-то свойство. Потом этот объект уничтожается сам. А примитив как был так и есть.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev шпашыба :3